# Problems integrating Gerrit server in Tuleap

Tags: git, gerrit, tuleap

I want to integrate Tuleap and Gerrit. I followed the procedure laid out in the [official Tuleap documentation](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/gerrit.html#connect-gerrit-and-tuleap-servers), with Tuleap v7.5.99.72 and Gerrit v2.9, but I can't find the menu item to configure my Gerrit server in Git service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is available in site admin section / Git plugin (box on the bottom right)

Comment: thanks for your response, but I talk about migration panel to gerrit in the git repository

Comment: The pane will only appear if you are using LDAP authentication (with LDAP plugin properly set up)